# How do I save a functions return value in a string

Tags: android

Check out this post [Reading a json file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814503/reading-a-json-file-in-android). What do I replace the below line with-

```
json_return_by_the_function
```

I need to save the functions return value in string.

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("file_name.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_return_by_the_function);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

Answer (score 0):

The Return value is all ready string

String str1 = loadJSONFromAsset();

Save it where ever u want and then parse

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str1 );

Comment: ok see my this post my textfile here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331257/how-to-search-value-from-textfile  suppose if i filter file to get only that school which name are "MiddleSchool" how i wil do that????