# Android XML array with multiple properties

Tags: android, android-xml

I have the following in my res/values/config.xml file

```
<string-array name="languages">
    <item display="english" code="GB" lang="en" flag="flag_uk" values="en-GB" eng="English (United Kingdom)" />
    <item display="svenska" code="SE" lang="sv" flag="flag_sv" values="sv" eng="Swedish" />
</string-array>
```

I think you get the picture. I cannot seem to access the item properties. Hows does one do this. Also IS this the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a string array. You can access the whole of it by using:

```
getResources().getStringArray()
```

from a context. It will return a simple array that you can iterate.

Comment: Ok so I use the metod to put the data into a String[], How do I extract, let's say, the flag property now?

Comment: Sorry you can't use the string-array entities like that. "items" don't have any attribute. You'll have to create your own XML file and parse it (do not put the xml file in any values- folder, use a "raw" folder so Android build system will not compile it).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access multiple properties with a string-array in values as far as i know.

But what you see here is XML. you can parse the XML with an XML parser.

What i would suggest as the best option for static data is to have this as an XML file into assets or values/raw and use an XML parser to parse into an array of objects.

Alternatively you can save it as JSON so its easier to parse.

try this:

[Android Java; How can I parse a local JSON file from assets folder into a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi)