# Cannot fill the list with content of json file in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to add content of a json file to an arraylist. I have done this a couple of times before but I cannot figure out what is wrong in this particular case that I cannot add anything to the arraylist.

So I have a :

```
private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

and this is how I **load the json file** from assets folder ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945484/4576720)):

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            // json file name
            InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("file.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

and **to write**:

```
public void writeJson(){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray response = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset());


        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            JSONObject jo_inside = response.getJSONObject(i);

            Log.d(TAG, jo_inside.getString("firstName"));

            //Add values in `ArrayList`
            person.setName(obj.getString("firstName"));
            person.setAge(obj.getString("age"));
            person.setPhoto(obj.getInt("id"));
            // Add to the array
            persons.add(person);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I try to print the content of persons array for testing purposes, I get nothing using the above method. However, if I insert a person like this :

```
persons.add(new Person("John", "23 years old", 1));
```

then it will be added to the array.

I think there is a minor mistake somewhere but I can't find the solution.

Comment: You've only got a single `Person` object - you're changing the properties of that `Person` on each iteration of the loop, but adding multiple references to the same object to the list. That may not be the only problem, but it's a significant one.

Comment: I'd also advise you to be more precise around terminology - you have a list, not an array. An array would be something like `Person[]`. (An `ArrayList` is a list which is backed by an array internally.)

Comment: put this line  Person person = new Person(); with in the for loop

Comment: @luckwithu yes, I have tried that before and it didnt work

Comment: "It didn't work" provides us with almost zero information. What happened? What have you tried to diagnose this? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? What happened?

Comment: (I would also point out that you shouldn't use `InputStream.available()` like this. You should pretty much always loop, reading until `read` returns -1.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, when I tried to print the content of the list, it printed nothing. Also nothing was printed on the screen when trying to pass the firstname

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when trying to pass the firstname" - but you should step through in a debugger.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using an adapter to pass each value to a textview

Comment: @JonSkeet in the logcat, it doesnt show any error

Comment: It's still not clear whether you've tried debugging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few corrections needed in your code. Check the comments in the code block.

```
    public void writeJson(){
    try {
        //this line is not needed, since you are reading array & not not json object 
        //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray response = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset());

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = response.getJSONObject(i);

            Log.d(TAG, jo_inside.getString("firstName"));

            //Add values in `ArrayList`
            //for setting the values use object read from response array 
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(jo_inside.getString("firstName"));
            person.setAge(jo_inside.getString("age"));
            person.setPhoto(jo_inside.getInt("id"));
            // Add to the array
            persons.add(person);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

This shall solve your issue.

Comment: thank you. It is late night here and I just couldn't figure out the problem. thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: you are adding the same person object to list every time. so all the persons have same data according to your code

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi that is not correct, the answer resolved the issue.

Comment: @RainMan the point raised by Gopal is correct to avoid issues related to object references. I updated the code to address it.

Comment: @Ashwini oh I see, I modified the code and brought the Person inside the loop before applying your changes so in my case it worked with previous answer.