# How to store json object to shared preferences?

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I am creating an application,In my app I am getting response and displaing it in custom alert dialog, Till here it works fine, Now what I am trying to do is if user selects an item from alert dialog once, it should store it in preference so that no need of fetch the data every time.

Following is my code snippet.

The following response which i am getting is :

```
    {
    "states": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "state_slug": "agra",
            "statename": "Agra"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "state_slug": "andaman_and_nicobar_islands",
            "statename": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "state_slug": "andhra_pradesh",
            "statename": "Andhra Pradesh"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "state_slug": "arunachal_pradesh",
            "statename": "Arunachal Pradesh"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "state_slug": "assam",
            "statename": "Assam"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "state_slug": "bihar",
            "statename": "Bihar"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "state_slug": "bulandshahr",
            "statename": "Bulandshahr"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "state_slug": "chhattisgarh",
            "statename": "Chhattisgarh"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "state_slug": "dadra_and_nagar_haveli",
            "statename": "Dadra & Nagar Haveli"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "state_slug": "daman_and_diu",
            "statename": "Daman & Diu"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "state_slug": "delhi",
            "statename": "Delhi"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "state_slug": "farrukhabad",
            "statename": "Farrukhabad"
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "state_slug": "goa",
            "statename": "Goa"
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "state_slug": "gujarat",
            "statename": "Gujarat"
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "state_slug": "haryana",
            "statename": "Haryana"
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "state_slug": "himachal_pradesh",
            "statename": "Himachal Pradesh"
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "state_slug": "jammu_and_kashmir",
            "statename": "Jammu & Kashmir"
        },
        {
            "id": "18",
            "state_slug": "jharkhand",
            "statename": "Jharkhand"
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "state_slug": "karnataka",
            "statename": "Karnataka"
        },
        {
            "id": "20",
            "state_slug": "kerala",
            "statename": "Kerala"
        },
        {
            "id": "21",
            "state_slug": "lakshadweep",
            "statename": "Lakshadweep"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "state_slug": "madhya_pradesh",
            "statename": "Madhya Pradesh"
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "state_slug": "maharashtra",
            "statename": "Maharashtra"
        },
        {
            "id": "24",
            "state_slug": "manipur",
            "statename": "Manipur"
        },
        {
            "id": "25",
            "state_slug": "meghalaya",
            "statename": "Meghalaya"
        },
        {
            "id": "26",
            "state_slug": "mizoram",
            "statename": "Mizoram"
        },
        {
            "id": "27",
            "state_slug": "nagaland",
            "statename": "Nagaland"
        },
        {
            "id": "28",
            "state_slug": "orissa",
            "statename": "Orissa"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "state_slug": "pondicherry",
            "statename": "Pondicherry"
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "state_slug": "punjab",
            "statename": "Punjab"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "state_slug": "purulia",
            "statename": "Purulia"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "state_slug": "rajasthan",
            "statename": "Rajasthan"
        },
        {
            "id": "33",
            "state_slug": "sikkim",
            "statename": "Sikkim"
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "state_slug": "tamil_nadu",
            "statename": "Tamil Nadu"
        },
        {
            "id": "35",
            "state_slug": "tripura",
            "statename": "Tripura"
        },
        {
            "id": "36",
            "state_slug": "uttar_pradesh",
            "statename": "Uttar Pradesh"
        },
        {
            "id": "37",
            "state_slug": "uttarakhand",
            "statename": "Uttarakhand"
        },
        {
            "id": "38",
            "state_slug": "west_bengal",
            "statename": "West Bengal"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am displaying statename in my alert dialog,

```
class LoadAllStates extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapterallstates ;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
               // pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                statedata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(STATE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        state_list = jsonObj.getJSONArray(COUNTRY_LIST);

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < state_list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = state_list.getJSONObject(i);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                              map.put(STATE_SLG, c.getString(STATE_SLG));
                          map.put(STATE_ID, c.getString(STATE_ID));
                            map.put(STATE_NAME,c.getString(STATE_NAME));

                           statedata.add(map);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

                return statedata;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
               pDialog.dismiss();

                String[] arrallstates=new String[statedata.size()];
                for(int index=0;index<statedata.size();index++){
                          HashMap<String, String> map=statedata.get(index);
                      arrallstates[index]=map.get(STATE_NAME);
                 }  


                 // pass arrConuntry array to ArrayAdapter<String> constroctor :
                adapterallstates = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                                                          arrallstates);
                spstate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View w) {
                          new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                          .setTitle("Select")
                          .setAdapter(adapterallstates, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                spstate.setText(adapterallstates.getItem(which).toString());

                                 try {

                                     String n  = state_list.getJSONObject(which).getString("state_slug");


                                    statename=state_list.getJSONObject(which).getString("state_slug");
                                    stnm=state_list.getJSONObject(which).getString(STATE_NAME);

                                     Log.d("Response statenm: ", "> " + statename);

                                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                                        editor.putString(States, n);
                                        editor.commit();
                                     new LoadAllStatesCity().execute();

                                    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), statename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                              dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                          }).create().show();
                        }
                });

            }
     }
```

Comment: you could write in a file? beter than storing a json response in sp?

Comment: you want to store only selected value? or entire response?

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @RahulTiwari if user select gujarat then it should remain selected untill user change it..

Comment: @Droidwala the problem is every time i am loading state name and selecting it..so i need to load it once and select it and make it selected until user chagne it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to store the response the better way is to write the content into a file.if you want to store only some values you can do like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("key_from_json", "String_value_from_json");
 editor.putInt("key_from_json","int_value_from_json");
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can store your whole object class in preference using 
[gson.jar file -> click here](https://github.com/google/gson)

And to use it...

```
static public void setPreferenceObject(Context c, Object modal,String key) {
    /**** storing object in preferences  ****/
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            c.getApplicationContext());
    Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonObject = gson.toJson(modal);
    prefsEditor.putString(key, jsonObject);
    prefsEditor.commit();

}

static public Object getPreferenceObjectJson(Context c,String key) {

    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            c.getApplicationContext());
    /**** get user data    *****/
    String json = appSharedPrefs.getString(key, "");
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    User selectedUser=gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
    return  selectedUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**`SharedPreferences` it is prefered for storing small data**. Hence to save your `entire response` it is better you save it to a file (ex: `.bin`) like so:

```
 public static synchronized void saveToFileSystem(Context context, Object object, String binFileName) {
        try {
            String tempPath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + binFileName + ".bin";
            File file = new File(tempPath);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and for reading it you can do smth like:

```
public static synchronized Object readFromFileSystem(Context context, String binFileName) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        try {
            String tempPath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + binFileName + ".bin";
            File file = new File(tempPath);
            if (file.exists()) {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                obj = ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: pls explain..whats this bin file?

Comment: @learner Its just a type of file. You can use any other file type. It was just an example

Comment: You can also convert it to `jsonString` through `Gson` and vise versa when retrieving it

Answer (score 1):

You can easily save your **JSON file completely as a string variable** with a key in shared preferences and pars it when you aim to read it again.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to store JSON object to shared preference is
Just make a JSONObject add values to JSONObject at last save to preference with **toString**

```
 private void storeDataToPref() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("localpref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", "hello");
        jsonObject.put("number", "aaaa");
        android.util.Log.d("response", jsonObject.toString());
        editor.putString("pref_data", jsonObject.toString()).commit();
    } catch (JSONException json) {

    }
}
```

For getting result from shared preference first of all read string convert into jsonobject and get your desire value thats solve hope this will help you all thanks

```
private void getDataFromPref() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("localpref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = sharedPreferences.getString("pref_data", "");
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(value);
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        String number = jsonObject.getString("number");
        android.util.Log.d("result", name + "...." + number);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the selected value in a key in SharedPreferences. Then, at startup, you'll be able to load SharedPreferences to check whether you already have a value or not (and in that case, you can reload your JSON entirely)

Guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

IMMO, it's useless to save a file if you're just looking for storing a value. That's where SharedPreferences are supposed to be used: they are kept even if you close your application and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Data for states does not change for years so you can keep this [json data in assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi) and use it from there or keep it in a [static map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialize-a-static-map). instead of calling webservice to fetch it.

for persisting the selected value, you can use `SharedPreferences` and store state `id` in it. next time whenever you inflate list of states you can check in your shared preference and select the one which is saved.

Comment: can you help me with my question?

Comment: which answer of yours?

Comment: i mean in my code i am getting and display json response in dialog

Comment: please try approach from my answer. let me know if you face problem while trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could check if the value of preferences is stored or not.

you could do this onCreate() method:
Check if preference value exists
**if yes:**
then no need to make AsyncTask call
**and if no:**
then make the AsyncTask call

Code:

```
String statename = preferences.getString("STATE_NAME<name you gave while committing for first time>,"");
 if(statename!=""){
   //Then directly go inside main activity

 }
 else{
//Make AsyncTask Call

 }
```

Comment: so what if first user want to change?

Comment: sorry i didn't get it ?what do you mean to say?

Comment: @Lakhan do you mean to ask how to change the state once set by user?

Comment: Then inside mainactivity you could provide option to user to click on some button or menu option whichever is best and once he clicks on it you once again use the above code and get the json resullts in dialog box and allow him to select it..once selected you change the preferences setting the new state.. Clear?

Comment: yes clear but i cant use another extra button or something

Comment: you need to use something like that to help user change his/her state..Or else create separate profile activity page containing his/her personal details from where he could change his/her state..Profile activity page could be accessed from navigation drawer if that works out for you..

Comment: Thank you for time but i can not change the view of my project which is already done...

Comment: Dude..then what exact answer are you looking for over here?!!