# Android - toString on JSONArray make json invalid with double quotes and backslashes

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have an app that let users create a `JSON`. Think about a house with some rooms: the user adds the rooms and the objects inside them. First he says how many rooms are there, then, with `Fragments`, says how many objects are in there. For every object I have a name, an image and an audio.

The fact is that I have a `JSONArray` with every room, and I can see every objects. E.g.:

```
for (int j = 0; j < lastArray.length(); j++) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAGADD, "item inserted: " + lastArray.get(j).toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAGADD, "errorjson: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

In the log I can see this:

```
item inserted: {"title":"room1","image":"2015-12-02-191546_241x190_scrot.png","audio":"","items":[{"title":"obj1","image":"2015-12-02-191615_207x185_scrot.png","audio":"recording1537733679498.mp3"}]}
item inserted: {"title":"room2","image":"16366","audio":"","items":[{"title":"obj2","image":"2015-12-02-191625_222x200_scrot.png","audio":"recording1537733694671.mp3"}]}
```

And it's fine. Now the problems: this `JSON` must be send to 1. another activity 2. a server. I read everywhere that I've to use `toString()` but when I do it I get an invalid `JSON` because the method puts some double quotes and some backslashes (the behavior is identical both with the preferences and with the writing in a file).

In the new Activity I get:

```
["{\"title\":\"room1\",\"image\":\"2015-12-02-191546_241x190_scrot.png\",\"audio\":\"\",\"items\":[{\"title\":\"obj1\",\"image\":\"2015-12-02-191615_207x185_scrot.png\",\"audio\":\"recording1537733679498.mp3\"}]}","{\"title\":\"room2\",\"image\":\"16366\",\"audio\":\"\",\"items\":[{\"title\":\"obj2\",\"image\":\"2015-12-02-191625_222x200_scrot.png\",\"audio\":\"recording1537733694671.mp3\"}]}"]}
 ^this is a problem (there is one also at the end)                    ^these are problems
```

Why does it only happen at the end and not with every object? What can I do to send the json correctly? Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

For read/write array:

In fragments:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("fullArray", lastArray.toString());
edit.apply();
```

In Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String arr = prefs.getString("fullArray", null);
Log.d("aftroomadd","read arr: "+arr);
```

The log returns this:

```
read arr: ["{\"title\":\"r1\",\"image\":\"2015-12-02-191546_241x190_scrot.png\",\"audio\":\"\",\"items\":[{\"title\":\"o1\",\"image\":\"2015-12-02-191615_207x185_scrot.png\",\"audio\":\"AUD-20180828-WA0011.mp3\"}]}","{\"title\":\"r2\",\"image\":\"16366\",\"audio\":\"\",\"items\":[{\"title\":\"o2\",\"image\":\"2015-12-02-191625_222x200_scrot.png\",\"audio\":\"AUD-20180828-WA0012.mp3\"}]}"]
```

I also tried to write the array in a file like:

```
public static synchronized void saveToFileSystem(Context context, Object object, String binFileName) {
    try {
        String tempPath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + binFileName;
        File file = new File(tempPath);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

saveToFileSystem(getContext(),fullEx.toString(),"tempFileJson");
```

But it's the same.

**(Not at all) Solution**

Since when I print the individual `JSONObject` the `toString()` works correctly, I thought (as ʍѳђઽ૯ท suggests in a comment) to use an array. I create a `String[]` in which I add every single object.

In fragment:

```
String[] a = new String[lastArray.length()];
for (int j = 0; j < lastArray.length(); j++) {
    try {
        a[j]= lastArray.get(j).toString();
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAGADD, "errorjson: " + e.toString());
    }
 }
 getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadExActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("jsonArray", a);
 startActivity(i);
```

Then, in the Activity to make the json a single string:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] arr = intent.getStringArrayExtra("jsonArray");
String t, full;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int size = arr.length;
int i=0;
for(String s : arr) {
    Log.d("aftroomadd", "read arr: " +s);
    builder.append(s);
    if(size-i>1)
        builder.append(",");
    i++;
}

t= builder.toString();

full = "[" + t + "]";
Log.d("aftroomadd", "final json in string: "+full);
```

Comment: Please paste the codes which you sent-read from another `Activity`. Anyways, `toString()` just converts the data to String and I don't think that might be the issue in here.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท added. Note that in the loop the individual objects are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
String arr = prefs.getString("fullArray", null);
```

Convert it back to `Json` like this:

```
String arr = prefs.getString("fullArray", null);
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(arr); // Or new JsonArray or whatever json is
Log.d("My converted Json" + jsonObject);
```

And then it should return the right value.

Comment: I tried `new JSONArray(arr)` and I still get `["{\"title\":\"r1\" //and so on`

Comment: SharedPreferences is ideal for small data and not a json output like that so that might be the issue. However, I’d save it in an Array or check this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208205/how-to-store-json-object-to-shared-preferences

Comment: As I said in the question, I've already tried with a file. Anyway I saved every JSONObjects in a `String[]` and it seems that it works (for now). If no other problems appear, I set your answer as the best since I follow your array tip