# How to store json data to shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I need to store the `userid` in a shared preference and use it in a second activity, but I don't know how to do it. How can I only store the `id` and recall it in an second activity?

Here is my code:

```
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        Boolean esito = response.getBoolean("Esito");

                        if (esito) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Dati");

                            Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(esito));

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject dato = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = dato.getString("id");
                                String fullname = dato.getString("fullname");
                                String username = dato.getString("username");
                                String password = dato.getString("password");


                                //mTextViewResult.append(id + ", " + fullname +  ", " + username +  ", " + password + "\n\n");

                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoggedActivity.class));

                            }
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Use putExtra :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store json object to shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208205/how-to-store-json-object-to-shared-preferences)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the data in the second activity then simply use intent to pass data and, Intent has `putExtra()` method, by using this method you can pass data between activities.

see this,

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        Boolean esito = response.getBoolean("Esito");

                        if (esito) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Dati");

                            Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(esito));

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject dato = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = dato.getString("id");
                                String fullname = dato.getString("fullname");
                                String username = dato.getString("username");
                                String password = dato.getString("password");


                                //mTextViewResult.append(id + ", " + fullname +  ", " + username +  ", " + password + "\n\n");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoggedActivity.class)
                                intent.putExtra("id",id);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
```

but if you want really to store data in `SharedPreference` then use this,

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        Boolean esito = response.getBoolean("Esito");

                        if (esito) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Dati");

                            Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(esito));

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject dato = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = dato.getString("id");
                                String fullname = dato.getString("fullname");
                                String username = dato.getString("username");
                                String password = dato.getString("password");

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_SHARED_PEREFENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                editor.putString("id", id);
                                editor.commit();

                                //mTextViewResult.append(id + ", " + fullname +  ", " + username +  ", " + password + "\n\n");

                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoggedActivity.class));

                            }
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        Boolean esito = response.getBoolean("Esito");

                        if (esito) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Dati");

                            Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(esito));

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject dato = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = dato.getString("id");
                                String fullname = dato.getString("fullname");
                                String username = dato.getString("username");
                                String password = dato.getString("password");

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("id", id);
 editor.putString("fullname", fullname);
 editor.putString("username", username);
 editor.putString("password", password);
 editor.commit();
                                //mTextViewResult.append(id + ", " + fullname +  ", " + username +  ", " + password + "\n\n");

                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoggedActivity.class));

                            }
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
```