# Json object from.json file

Tags: android, json, android-assets, android-json

I have json file:"document.json" in assets folder

document.json:

```
{
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

Can i do this to get the string in android from a json file?

```
JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(R.assets.document);
string response = jresponse.getString("string");
```

Am i doing something wrong or is it correct?

Is there any method where we pass .json file and get the required string?

Comment: JsonObject doesn't take an R.assets resource... Isn't that an integer?

Comment: Here you go : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi

Comment: As far as "is it correct?" well, it probably won't compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, You have to read the `JSON` from assets first**

```
 InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("document.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String myJson = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

**Then you can parse that**

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myJson);
String myFinalString = obj.getString("")
```

[For further help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi)

Comment: initially it gives error `FileNotFound Exception`. then i change file name and remove extension `.json` it works fine now.Thnaks