# Navigation drawer material design-using the local JSON file in res/raw folder

Tags: android

I have a JSON file within my res/raw folder in android studio and I want to use that as my Navigation drawers List Items. I have not found a suitable tutorial to help me out. Is it possible to do this? 
Please if anyone knows a way where it is easy to understand and implement this, a tutorial or video etc would be great.

Comment: any specific reason for implementing it through file? ..you can store a json string and use gson.. convert it into model object which can be passed to the adapter of navigation drawer list items

Comment: I have actually been given an assignment. I've been asked to read a JSON file as the list items in the drawer.

Comment: :) appreciate your honesty though stackoverflow is intended for, when you face errors, issues after starting development, lets not make it a help-me-tutorial-ready-code place

Comment: I am sorry but I only intended a tutorial because I have not provided code. I don't really need a ready code. I just need an understand of how JSON would work here and where I should start.

Comment: thats ok, didn't tell you that for a sorry.. try googling more though..here are a few.. [listview data from json](http://www.kaleidosblog.com/android-listview-load-data-from-json), [...from assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi), [gson used to parse json](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)

Comment: appreciate it...thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_file);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try {
  Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
  int n;
  while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
   }
 } finally {
is.close();
}

String jsonString = writer.toString();
```