# How to load JSON data from asset folder into Recyclerview and Cardview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i get stuck in my data in `RecyclerView`. I have a json in asset folder like this :

```
"tTisch": {
        "t-tisch": [
            {
                "tischnr": 1,
                "departement": 1,
                "normalbeleg": 0,
                "kellner-nr": 0,
                "bezeich": "TABLE 01",
                "roomcharge": false,
                "betriebsnr": 0
            },
            {
                "tischnr": 2,
                "departement": 1,
                "normalbeleg": 0,
                "kellner-nr": 0,
                "bezeich": "TABLE 02",
                "roomcharge": false,
                "betriebsnr": 0
            },
            {
                "tischnr": 3,
                "departement": 1,
                "normalbeleg": 0,
                "kellner-nr": 0,
                "bezeich": "TABLE 03",
                "roomcharge": false,
                "betriebsnr": 0
            },
    .......
```

I want to load this data into my `RecyclerView` and `CardView`. I have read many tutorials but there is none regarding my case. Every tutorial for `RecyclerView` always loads json from internet. This is my codes :

Item.java

```
public class Item {
private String txt_no_table;
private String txt_pax;
private String txt_time;
private String txt_guestname;
private String txt_bill;

Item(String txt_no_table, String txt_pax, String txt_time, String txt_guestname, String txt_bill) {
    this.txt_no_table = txt_no_table;
    this.txt_pax = txt_pax;
    this.txt_time = txt_time;
    this.txt_guestname = txt_guestname;
    this.txt_bill = txt_bill;
}

public String getTxt_no_table() {
    return txt_no_table;
}

public String getTxt_pax() {
    return txt_pax;
}

public String getTxt_time() {
    return txt_time;
}

public String getTxt_guestname() {
    return txt_guestname;
}

public String getTxt_bill() { return txt_bill; }
}
```

This is Adapter.java :

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = Adapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<Item> items;

Context context;
List<Item> item;

public Adapter() {
    super();
    this.item = item;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.table_item_occupied, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Item item = items.get(position);

    holder.txt_no_table.setText(item.getTxt_no_table());
    holder.txt_pax.setText(item.getTxt_pax());
    holder.txt_time.setText(item.getTxt_time());
    holder.txt_guestname.setText(item.getTxt_guestname());
    holder.txt_bill.setText(item.getTxt_bill());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_no_table;
    TextView txt_pax;
    TextView txt_time;
    TextView txt_guestname;
    TextView txt_bill;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txt_no_table= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_no_table);
        txt_pax = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pax);
        txt_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
        txt_guestname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_guestname);
        txt_bill = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_bill);
    }
}
}
```

This is my Activity :

```
public class TableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

private static final String TAG = TableActivity.class.getSimpleName();
List<Item> items;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
JSONArray array;

public static String AssetJSONFile (String filename, Context context) throws IOException {
    AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream file = manager.open(filename);
    byte[] formArray = new byte[file.available()];
    file.read(formArray);
    file.close();

    return new String(formArray);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

    try {
        loadJSONFromAsset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.table_rv);
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 6));
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

public void loadJSONFromAsset() throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = null;
    Item items2 = new Item();
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("tableplan.json");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();

    for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            items2.set_txt_no_table(json.getString("bezeich"));
            items2.set_txt_pax(json.getString("normalbeleg"));
            items2.set_txt_time(json.getString("betriebsnr"));
            items2.set_txt_guestname(json.getString("betriebsnr"));
            items2.set_txt_bill(json.getString("betriebsnr"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        items.add(items2);
    }
    recyclerViewadapter = new Adapter(items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
}
```

My referencec : https://www.codeproject.com/tips/631546/parse-json-data-in-android
EDITED:
my app force stop and i get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.development_laptop.vhp_restotemp, PID: 7897
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.development_laptop.vhp_restotemp/com.example.development_laptop.vhp_restotemp.TableActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.development_laptop.vhp_restotemp.TableActivity.loadJSONFromAsset(TableActivity.java:79)
                  at com.example.development_laptop.vhp_restotemp.TableActivity.onCreate(TableActivity.java:54)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Every answer is very helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19945484/5425930

Comment: [Try this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi)

Comment: i follow that sugest, now i get error in `InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("yourfilename.json")` in cannot resolve method getActivity

Comment: remove `getActivity()`. it used when you are dealing with Fragments. as i can see you are extending Activity, no need to write `getActivity()`. and try again.

Comment: @vrundpurohit ok its done, now i get error in 'JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());' its say unhandledexception:org.json.JSONEXCEPTION. i'll edit my activity code

Comment: wrap it inside try and catch statement.

Comment: @vrundpurohit the first `try` say Unexpected token. sory i'm beginer in java language :(

Comment: This code doesn't even compile... `new HashMap<String, String, String, String, String>`... Besides that `public Adapter()` is just wrong. If you are a beginner, then *learn Java*, not dive so deep into the complexities of Android

Comment: @cricket_007 its mistake i dont see it, its should `<String String>` only, i edit again my code

Comment: Okay, looks better. Is there any reason you are not using Gson? I think that can load from a File object.

Comment: @cricket_007 i'm not familiar with Gson

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
public void loadJSONFromAsset() throws IOException, JSONException {
    String json = null;
    InputStream is = activity.getAssets().open("tableplan.json");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("t-tisch");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> m_li;

    for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("formule"));
        String getTxt_no_table = jo_inside.getString("bezeich");
        String getTxt_pax = jo_inside.getString("normalbeleg");
        String getTxt_time = jo_inside.getString("kellner-nr");
        String getTxt_guestname = jo_inside.getString("betriebsnr");
        String getTxt_bill = jo_inside.getString("kellner-nr");

        m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m_li.put("bezeich", getTxt_no_table);
        m_li.put("normalbeleg", getTxt_pax);
        m_li.put("kellner-nr", getTxt_time);
        m_li.put("betriebsnr", getTxt_guestname);
        m_li.put("kellner-nr", getTxt_bill);

        formList.add(m_li);
    }
}
```

and call this method inside `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

    try {
        loadJSONFromAsset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.table_rv);
    item1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter());
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 6));
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
```

I Hope this will help

Comment: This just creates an empty adapter. Should you load data into it?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes there should be data loaded into Adapter. I was so focused about his error, so i didn't noticed that he is not using data in Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read many tutorials but there is none regarding my case. Every tutorial for RecyclerView always loads json from internet

Here's the thing - Whether you read from a file, or from the internet, you get a `String`. All you need to know is how to get an asset file into a `String` to follow any of those tutorials. The remaining JSON parsing should be the exact same.

And you seem to have that method already, so I do not know why you aren't using it.

```
public static String AssetJSONFile (String filename, Context context) throws IOException {
```

---

Now, looking at your Adapter class, you have two different lists and your constuctor isn't initializing anything but null.

```
private List<Item> items; // null

Context context; // null
List<Item> item; // null

public Adapter() {
    super();
    this.item = item;  // null
    this.context = context; // null
}
```

You need to pass in some parameters to the adapter.

```
private List<Item> items; // Only one list

public Adapter(Context ctx, List<Item> items) {
    super();
    this.items = items; 
    this.context = ctx;
}
```

---

And the rest of the issues are related to the fact that you need probably need the list initialized **before** you load anything into it.

Your NullPointerException is the fact that you never assigned anything to `array` before you started looping over it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.table_rv);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 6));

    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        jsonString = AssetJSONFile("tableplan.json", TableActivity.this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    if (jsonString != null) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        // TODO: parse data into 'new Item()' objects
        // items.add(item);
    }

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(TableActivity.this, items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

My final Activity :

```
public class TableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

private static final String TAG = TableActivity.class.getSimpleName();
List<Item> items;
RecyclerView recyclerView;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);



    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.table_rv);
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 6));
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    writeJSON();

}

public void writeJSON() {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray tablelist = json.getJSONObject("response")
                .getJSONObject("tTisch").getJSONArray("t-tisch");

        for (int i = 0; i < tablelist.length(); i++) {
            Item items2 = new Item();
            JSONObject AllTable = tablelist.getJSONObject(i);

            items2.set_txt_no_table(AllTable.getString("bezeich"));
            items2.set_txt_pax(AllTable.getString("normalbeleg"));
            items2.set_txt_time(AllTable.getString("betriebsnr"));
            items2.set_txt_guestname(AllTable.getString("betriebsnr"));
            items.add(items2);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(TableActivity.this, items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("tableplan.json");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        Log.d("X","Response Ready:"+stringBuilder.toString());

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.deptes:
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

            return true;

        case R.id.deptes2:
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

            return true;

        case R.id.deptes3:
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

            return true;

        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

Thanks everyone for helpful answer and suggest