# How to access json with object inside object

Tags: android, json

[Json Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ7nQ.png)

I have the above json document. How can I access Product1 and Product2 in it.
it's like

```
{
  "abc": "abc",
  "xyz": "xyz",
  "proudct1": {
    "id": "id",
    "name": "name"
  },
  "proudct2": {
    "id": "id",
    "name": "name"
  }
}
```

Comment: learn how to parse json first and try it for your self if you are having any issue while parsing, then post it here .

Comment: Create getter setter using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ .

Comment: @Redman I know how to parse json but can't understand how to access object within object.

Comment: @SatanPandeya Thanks but I don't want to use these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have multiable products. Your json is not effective.Products must be json array like

```
{
  "product": "Product Data",
  "version": 1.1,
  "releaseDate": "2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
  "demo": true,
  "products": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "isDisplayed": "Yes",
      "Title1": "Microsoft",
      "Title2": "India",
      "URL": "abc",
      "ImageName": "Microsoft Logo",
      "isImgDownloaded": "Yes",
      "ImageURL": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "isDisplayed": "Yes",
      "Title1": "Google",
      "Title2": "India",
      "URL": "abc",
      "ImageName": "Google Logo",
      "isImgDownloaded": "Yes",
      "ImageURL": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

And you can access jsonarray object like this

```
JSONArray result = jsonString.getJSONArray("products");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObjectItem = result.getJSONObject(i);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: voting up as it also suggest efficient structure :)

Comment: I have updated my json and trying to access it through assets folder but the following error occurs while building

C:\Users\Abhinav\AndroidStudioProjects\Internship\app\src\main\res\assets\demo.json

Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 

C:\Users\Abhinav\AndroidStudioProjects\Internship\app\src\main\res\assets\demo.json:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19945484/1929448)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONOBject`, it comes bundled with SDK so no need to import any third party lib.

Assume the above string is `response`.

```
JSONObject responseObj=new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject product1=responseObj.getJSONObject("product1");
String id=product1.getString("Id");
// ... and similarly for other keys
```