# How to display json data from assets folder in android studio into Recylerview

Tags: java, android

How to display json data from assets folder in android studio into Recylerview

Something like this:

```
{
  "book": "Luke",
  "chapters": 
  [
  {
  "chapter": "1",
   "verses":
  [
  {
   "1": "Forasmuch as many have taken in hand to set forth in order a declaration 
        of those things which are most surely believed among us,"
  }
  ]
  }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is a problem?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

They are many ways to do this based on the needs of your code.

One way, and the most simple, is doing the next steps:

- Read JSON from Asset an manage it as JSONObject without creating any model class.
- Read the array of elements you want to display from that JSONObject
- Create a custom Adapter to display objects from that array.

You can find some similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi)

Comment: What am failing to get is the book, chapter and verse.

Comment: How can i loop through this array to retrieve single item:["Genesis", "Exodus", "Leviticus", "Numbers", "Deuteronomy", "Joshua", "Judges", "Ruth", "1 Samuel", "2 Samuel", "1 Kings", "2 Kings", "1 Chronicles", "2 Chronicles", "Ezra", "Nehemiah", "Esther", "Job", "Psalms", "Proverbs", "Ecclesiastes", "Song of Solomon", "Isaiah", "Jeremiah", "Lamentations", "Ezekiel", "Daniel", "Hosea", "Joel", "Amos", "Obadiah", "Jonah", "Micah", "Nahum", "Habakkuk", "Zephaniah", "Haggai", "Zechariah", "Malachi", "Matthew", "Mark", "Luke", "John", "Acts" ]