# Most optimal way to load large JSON into a List<>

Tags: android

I am working on android multiplayer game. My JSON file contains 800 000+ dictionary words. JSON array is being loaded in List once players enter GameActivity to actually play game. So each time player starts 1vs1 game, JSON is being loaded into a List<>.

Now, I have 2 options:

1. Load JSON the most optimal way so user does not get out of memory error after a while
2. Load JSON file into a List<> only once, when application is open.

I'm not sure about any of these 2 cases, can someone give me a hand on how to do this please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of my repu.
But you can try to few different approaches into this problem.

If your JSON changes very rarely i can suggest [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi).

You can put your json inside your asset file. and call in runtime with this

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Or you can fetch your Json before app starts and store in ContentProvider (DB or SharedPreference). And this way you only fetch your json when it is necessary.

```
//right before fetching JSON
boolean thereIsAnyUpdatesInJSON = checkYourDictionaryJsonIfThereAreAnyUpdates();
if(!isDictionaryDatabaseAvailable && thereIsAnyUpdatesInJSON){
     fetchYourDictJson();
}
```

Comment: I'm using exact same fetch method.

I have tried to save List into sharedPreference, however, it's to large, I get an error. Dictionary has 800 000+ words. adding it to intent.putExtraArraylist..("x", arraylist); does not work too.

Comment: Then try to store inside DB but  you might need to split your dictionary for faster execution (like A-D,E-G etc...or something else if it wont fit your situation)