# Convert JSON to GSON to Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following structure in my Android project:

> map = new Gson().fromJson("[{\n       \"ques\": \"20+20=\",\n     \"a\":
>   \"40\",\n     \"b\": \"60\",\n        \"c\": \"80\",\n        \"d\":
>   \"220\",\n        \"ans\": \"a\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"80+80=\",\n     \"a\": \"60\",\n        \"b\": \"93\",\n        \"c\":
>   \"272\",\n        \"d\": \"160\",\n       \"ans\": \"d\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"50+50=\",\n     \"a\": \"100\",\n       \"b\": \"458\",\n       \"c\":
>   \"200\",\n        \"d\": \"90\",\n        \"ans\": \"a\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"25+25=\",\n     \"a\": \"78\",\n        \"b\": \"45\",\n        \"c\":
>   \"50\",\n     \"d\": \"43\",\n        \"ans\": \"c\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"60+90=\",\n     \"a\": \"56\",\n        \"b\": \"150\",\n       \"c\":
>   \"180\",\n        \"d\": \"100\",\n       \"ans\": \"b\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"75+5=\",\n      \"a\": \"60\",\n        \"b\": \"65\",\n        \"c\":
>   \"100\",\n        \"d\": \"80\",\n        \"ans\": \"d\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"60+70=\",\n     \"a\": \"150\",\n       \"b\": \"130\",\n       \"c\":
>   \"609\",\n        \"d\": \"517\",\n       \"ans\": \"b\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"50+10=\",\n     \"a\": \"60\",\n        \"b\": \"13\",\n        \"c\":
>   \"471\",\n        \"d\": \"100\",\n       \"ans\": \"a\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"90+90=\",\n     \"a\": \"180\",\n       \"b\": \"100\",\n       \"c\":
>   \"120\",\n        \"d\": \"145\",\n       \"ans\": \"a\"\n    },\n\n  {\n     \"ques\":
>   \"40+30=\",\n     \"a\": \"60\",\n        \"b\": \"50\",\n        \"c\":
>   \"70\",\n     \"d\": \"80\",\n        \"ans\": \"c\"\n    }\n]",
>                                   new TypeToken>>(){}.getType());

But it is very difficult to edit, how do I get GSON to load with the original JSON framework?

Comment: Load the json data from a file or at least use a proper IDE and do something like Alt+Enter > Inject Language Reference > Json

Comment: How do I load a file through Assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson uses its own parser and json types

If you want to use the builtin JSONArray class, then you would pass your string to that rather than Gson, however that wouldn't fix the difficulty of editing the string.

You should instead store it in the assets folder and read it as a file

[Android Java; How can I parse a local JSON file from assets folder into a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi)