# Android Studio having trouble reading a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm a beginner to Android Studio and I'm just learning how to read in JSON files. I used logcat to find out that I'm getting an exception on the line declaraing the JSONArray dataList. My code is below for reference.

```
try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray dataList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("eateries");
            //Log.d("test", String.valueOf(dataList.length()));
            for(int i = 0; i < dataList.length(); i++){
                String EateryName = dataList.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                EateryList.add(EateryName);
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.d("test", "exception");
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: just a jsonexception. my code is going into the catch part when i initialize the json array

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to solve your issue.

1. Check for asset folder/dir via code (file path must be accurate with .json).
2. Check for file created/present in dir using File object (if not then create file).
3. Check for file size by reading the file using FileInputStream.
4. If size > 0 then get data in byte-Array and convert byte-Array to string.
5. Now, you have a string of json data. Create JsonArray(your_string) and perform further operations you like.
   Every step has a code available on this stack overflow. Find and solve.
   Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check [GrIsHu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi)
simply you have to do is create **assests** folder in root of project

[image]

Here is the [original Link](https://bezkoder.com/java-android-read-json-file-assets-gson/)

```
String myJsonFileString = Utils.getJsonFromAssets(getApplicationContext(), "your.json");
Log.i("My data", jsonFileString);

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listUserType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() { }.getType();

List<User> users_ = gson.fromJson(myJsonFileString, listUserType);
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
  Log.i("data", "> Item " + i + "\n" + users.get(i));
}
```

go through original post