# Cannot read JSON in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

I want to read/parse a JSON file in Android Studio.

The JSON file, that is contained in the assets folder is this one:

```
{
   "Person":
   {
   "Name": "John"
   }
}
```

The class that is supposed to read the file is this one:

```
import ...

public class ParseJ
{
    private Context context;
    String name;


    public String RetName() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONObject student = obj.getJSONObject("Person");
        name = student.getString("Name");
        return name;
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset()
    {
        String json = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("Test.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Then it gets called in MainActivity like this:

````
String firstname = new String();
ParseJ parsetest = new ParseJ();
TextView onomaTView;


 try {
        firstname = parsetest.RetName();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //textview
    onomaTView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.onoma);

        onomaTView.setText("ONOMA:" + firstname);
    }                                  
```
````

When i build and run the app it crashes immediately and looking at the Logcat it says the following message:
*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference*

Which lets me to believe it cannot read the file and it just returns null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer because **Context** is null now
create a contructor and pass context in it like this

```
 public class ParseJ
    {
        private Context context;
        String name;
    
    public ParseJ(Context context){
    this.context = context
    }
```

then in Mainactivity while creating object of ParseJ

```
ParseJ parsetest = new ParseJ(this);
```

Comment: This does remove the error i've been getting but now i have a new error that says:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: can u tell me the at ehich line?

Comment: It's a bunch of them but here are some:at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:121)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:98)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:164)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)

Comment: can you add Xml file ? @Puhskintilio

Comment: No i have to do it with JSON.

Comment: where in xml onomaTView is defined @Puhskintilio

Comment: It's in MainActivity.xml

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">`

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/onoma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: ok, can u add full logcat error which u get or show me a screenshot of error

Comment: what is mainactivity line no 30?

Comment: and add a sscreenshot of mainactivity also

Comment: add this line ParseJ parsetest = new ParseJ(this); inside oncreate at line no 27

Comment: No it did not work i am sorry. Is there any helpful guide for JSON file reading in Android Studio?

Comment: youa re doing it wrong some where , i am not able to replicate, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LIXkNxUdhw
https://medium.com/@mananwason/how-to-parse-json-assets-with-gson-7b19dec6a34