# try catch code reading JSON file Android

Tags: java, android, json, try-catch

having some serious problem when trying to read a local JSON file. I've looked everywhere for many days now and the best and farthest I could get was copying from Faizan's answer.
[Reading a json file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814503/reading-a-json-file-in-android/13814551#13814551)

How come that Android Studio doesn't let me generate the second try-catch code block here?

Help and advice are very much appreciated!!

This is [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgGUb.png)

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("names.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

String jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset();

try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject jObject = json.getJSONObject("female");
    JSONObject jObject2 = jObject.getJSONObject("adult");
    String name = jObject2.toString();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

Comment: post your code within your description with good formatting. please don't use external links for people to see your code.

Comment: Also, the reason why Android shows an error on your try/catch is because it's not contained within a method.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come that Android Studio doesn't let me generate the second
>   try-catch code block here?

Simply, because your code is not inside a method.

Doing something like below should solve the error.

```
public void someMethodIdentifier(){ // doesn't have to be void return type, you know better than me what type you want to return.
    String jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset();
    try {
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
       JSONObject jObject = json.getJSONObject("female");
       JSONObject jObject2 = jObject.getJSONObject("adult");
       String name = jObject2.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Note** - from the looks of the statements that's contained within the `try` block I think you intended to return some data? if that's the case just replace the `void` return type with the appropriate return type and return that data.