# Android: Reading json from sampledata folder

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I would like to fill `RecyclerView` with my custom `operations.json` file which stays in sampledata folder. How can i read that sample json file? My `operations.json` file just looks like this:

```
{
  "data" :[
    { "name": "123", "image": "@drawable/ic_cloud_download_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "456", "image": "@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "789", "image": "@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "asd", "image": "@drawable/ic_alarm_off_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "qwe", "image": "@drawable/ic_assignment_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "rty", "image": "@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "asd", "image": "@drawable/ic_sms_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "fgh", "image": "@drawable/ic_print_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "zxc", "image": "@drawable/ic_library_books_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "vbn", "image": "@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "jkl", "image": "@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "yui", "image": "@drawable/ic_tv_black_24dp" },
    { "name": "ert", "image": "@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814503/reading-a-json-file-in-android

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. And exactly, what did you try?

Comment: Hi @DavidGarcíaBodego, sampledata folder is specific directory. I dont know this reading operation doable from that location. Therefore i havent tried anything. Searched over internet but there is no clue about reading file from sampledata folder.

Answer (score 4):

- First Create asset folder
- Place your json file inside asset folder

  [image: Asset folder]
- Read json file following code

  `private fun loadJSONFromAsset(): String? {
      val json: String?
      try {
          val inputStream = activity!!.assets.open("search_key.json")
          val size = inputStream.available()
          val buffer = ByteArray(size)
          inputStream.read(buffer)
          inputStream.close()
          json = String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
      } catch (ex: IOException) {
          ex.printStackTrace()
          return null
      }
      return json
  }`
- Parse your json using GSON library

  `val data = Gson().fromJson(loadJSONFromAsset(), Data::class.java)`

Answer (score 2):

You should do step by step as below or watching the tutorial ([using Kotlin Language](https://youtu.be/dxIDAJ_qkwg)):

- Create the `Assets` folder
- Add your `sample_data.json` to the `Assets` folder.
- Read the JSON from the `sample_data.json` file.
- Parse the JSON String to a data Model by using `Gson`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to copy json file to assets so, srcDirs better solution for that. Modification can be done in App's Gradle file:

```
android {
    sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs += file('sampleData')
}
```

Later this file can be read as asset file.